# How to remove old join operator and rewrite them with new queries in outer or inner joins

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, join

I have a insert statement which basically does inserts to a table from multiple tables. The queries written in insert statement have old way of writing join operations using =* join operator. I want to replace the join operator present and convert it to more readable format in SQL server 2008.

```
Insert into tmp
SELECT
tr.Port, 
tr.PortDate, 
tr.TrType,

tr.Cpcode,
tr.TrType, 
bsflag, 
vol, 
tr.trnumber,
MP = SUM(tr.MP * ( Case cd when 'USD' then 1.0 else (case fx.curr2 when 'USD' then fx.r ELSE 1/(fx.r) end) END)), 

GFE=SUM((case ar when 'R' then 1.0 else -1.0 end)*((ISNULL(tr.NE * ( Case cd when 'USD' then 1.0 else (case fx.curr2 when 'USD' then fx.r ELSE 1/(fx.r) end) END),0)))),

GPE = 0,                                     
FS = ISNULL(tmpFin.FinSec,0) * ISNULL(Conversion,1),
PS = 0, ar, @sessionid



FROM
tr

, tmpFin, fxr fx, tmpD, PhyFin p1

WHERE
tr.Trtype = p1.trtype
AND p1.PhyFin = 'F'
and p1.SType <> 'Option'


AND tmpFin.cpc =* tmpd.cpc

AND tmpFin.Port =* tr.port
AND tmpFin.Portdate =* t.portfoliodate
AND tr.Port = tmpD.Port
AND tr.cpc = tmpD.cpc
AND tr.Portdate = tmpD.Portdate
AND tmpFin.SessionId = @sessionid
AND tmpD.SessionId = @sessionid



AND 
(
    (
        (
        (
        tr.cd = fx.curr1

        AND




        fx.curr2 = 'USD'

        )
        OR
        (
        tr.cd = fx.curr2
        AND

        fx.curr1 = 'USD'
        )
        )
        And 
        fx.rd = (select max(rd) from ratefx where  tr.portdate >= rd and 
                (curr2 = tr.cd and curr1 = 'USD')
                OR (curr1 = tr.cd and curr2 = 'USD'))
    )
    OR
    (
    tr.cd = 'USD'
    AND
    fx.Curr1 = 'USD'
    AND
    fx.Curr2 = 'USD'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The side with the `*` character (`*=` or `=*`) represents the `OUTER JOIN` table. That is:

```
FROM t1, t2
WHERE t1.id *= t2.id
```

should become:

```
FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

So, I believe your query would become:

```
INSERT INTO tmp
SELECT
       tr.Port,
       tr.PortDate,
       tr.TrType,
       tr.Cpcode,
       tr.TrType,
       bsflag,
       vol,
       tr.trnumber,
       MP = SUM(tr.MP * ( CASE cd WHEN 'USD'
                            THEN 1.0
                            ELSE (CASE fx.curr2 WHEN 'USD'
                                    THEN fx.r
                                    ELSE 1/(fx.r)
                                  END
                                 )
                          END
                         )
               ), 
       GFE = SUM( (CASE ar WHEN 'R' THEN 1.0 ELSE -1.0 END)
                 *(ISNULL( tr.NE * ( CASE cd WHEN 'USD'
                                      THEN 1.0
                                      ELSE (CASE fx.curr2 WHEN 'USD'
                                              THEN fx.r
                                              ELSE 1/(fx.r)
                                            END
                                           )
                                    END
                                  )
                          ,0
                         )
                  )
                ),
       GPE = 0,                                     
       FS = ISNULL(tmpFin.FinSec,0) * ISNULL(Conversion,1),
       PS = 0, ar, @sessionid
FROM tr
       INNER JOIN fxr fx ON (
                                (
                                     (
                                         (tr.cd = fx.curr1 AND fx.curr2 = 'USD')
                                      OR (tr.cd = fx.curr2 AND fx.curr1 = 'USD')
                                     )
                                 AND fx.rd = (SELECT MAX(rd) FROM ratefx
                                               WHERE tr.portdate >= rd
                                                 AND (   curr2 = tr.cd and curr1 = 'USD'
                                                      OR curr1 = tr.cd and curr2 = 'USD'
                                                     )
                                             )
                                )
                             OR (    tr.cd = 'USD'
                                 AND fx.Curr1 = 'USD'
                                 AND fx.Curr2 = 'USD'
                                )
                            ) 
       INNER JOIN PhyFin p1 ON (tr.Trtype = p1.trtype)
       INNER JOIN tmpD ON (    tr.Port = tmpD.Port
                           AND tr.cpc = tmpD.cpc
                           AND tr.Portdate = tmpD.Portdate
                          )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN tmpFin ON (    tr.port = tmpFin.Port
                                  AND tr.portfoliodate = tmpFin.Portdate
                                  AND tmpD.cpc = tmpFin.cpc
                                 )
WHERE
p1.PhyFin = 'F'
AND p1.SType <> 'Option'
AND tmpFin.SessionId = @sessionid
AND tmpD.SessionId = @sessionid
```

Note - white space is ignored, so the layout I've provided is my personal preferred layout, not some that's a requirement. Similarly, my choice to list the fields from the current table after the `=` sign are personal preferences, not requirements. In addition, the `fxr` and `PhyFin` `INNER JOIN`s could come after the rest of the `JOIN`s.

However, since the `OUTER JOIN` condition that ties `tmpFin` to the rest of the tables relies on both `tr` and `tmpD`, both `tr` and `tmpD` should either come before `tmpFin` (in which case you'd have a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, as I used) or after `tmpFin` (in which case this would be a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`). If at all possible, it's recommended that you make all one-directional outer joins either `LEFT` or `RIGHT`. In my experience, most people are more comfortable using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, so the "more important" table (the one were bring back all records from, regardless of matches to the other table) is listed first.